# How can I generate code only for blocks in my file and not for imported files?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying create some CSS blocks based on Bootstrap's CSS, by using the [Sass extension mechanism](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/).

My problem is that `sass` command generates a large amount of CSS even for the sass modules I just imported from bootstrap and did not use myself in the "customization" file.

Say I have something like this

```scss
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/forms";

.bs-form input {
    @extend .form-control;
    @extend .form-control-lg;
}
```

Compiling this gives about 800 lines, and ~30KB of CSS.

I just want the code to emit the rules for `.bs-form input { .. }` block and I don't want anything else from `forms` to be even defined. It's okay if the clauses I `extend` are emitted to output CSS. But anything else (eg: `form-select`) should not be there in output CSS.

Eg: I want the output CSS to be just

```css
.bs-form input {
  /* Rules inherited from form-control */
  /* Rules inherited from form-control-lg */
}
```

Is this possible in any implementation of `sass`?